# DataIntegrityViolationException persisting one to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, one-to-many

Boot,Jpa and hibernate to persist a one-many relation between venues and events.

The error i'm retrieving is

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "VENUE_LOCATION"; SQL statement:
insert into event (id, date, description, media_ref, num_ratings, performer, performer_media, title, total_rating) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-192]
```

I've tried saving the parent(Venue) class first and exclusively but that produces the same error.

Venue

```
public class Venue
{
    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    private String location;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "venue",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private VenueUser venueUser;

    private String mediaRef;

    private int rating;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "venue",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events;
    //Constructors getters and setters below
```

Event

```
@Entity
public class Event 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

private String title;
private String description;
private String performer;
private String[] performerMedia;
private Calendar[] date;

@Transient
private double avgRating;

private int numRatings;
private int totalRating;

private String mediaRef;

@MapsId("name")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="Venue_name",referencedColumnName = "name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="venue_location",referencedColumnName = "location")
})
private Venue venue;
 //Constructors getters and setters below
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addEvent(@RequestBody Event event)
{
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
    Venue venue = userVenueRepository.findByEmail(name).getVenue();

    event.setVenue(venue);
    venue.addEvent(event);

    if(eventRepository.saveAndFlush(event).equals(event)&&venueRepository.saveAndFlush(venue).equals(venue))
    {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    else
    {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need not save parent entity in OneToMany relationship. You should save only event entity [child entity] and not venue entity.

Comment: I do see only ManyToOne annotation inside Event Entity and not the Venue field. Is it mistake in pasting or actual code.

Comment: Is not the case where one entity has the OneToMany annotation and the other ManyToOne, there is a OneToMany in Venue.

Comment: Are you still persisting parent entity?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into event (id, date, description, media_ref, num_ratings, performer, performer_media, title, total_rating) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

You need to set id to your Event entity. Better use `@GeneratedValue` annotation with `AUTO`, like here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.java

or use class AbstractPersistable as parent entity.

Comment: I tried using AUTO but I still received the same results.

Comment: Also tried extending the AbstractPersistable class using type Integer which didn't change much.

Comment: Hoh, I miss that error messsage is `NULL not allowed for column "VENUE_LOCATION";`. Please check your location, it must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Error says that `location` field of Venue entity is null which cannot be as it is primary key.

You have two options for persisting Event object.

1. First persist Venue [Parent] Entity and then Persist as many Event [Child] entities as you want.Set venue field in event entity. You need to save Parent entity only once.
2. If you want to persist both parent and child at once, you can specify `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` in Event Entity and then save child entity.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fixed this and in hindsight I shouldn't of blindly followed a tutorial, I wasn't to sure what the @MapsId did so I removed it and everything started working.If anyone could explain what @MapsId does and why it was causing problems that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this too.

> *this way you **don't need to add parent entry inside child** object.*

Remove mappedBy form `Venue` entity

Then add below code inside the `Venue` entity before `Set<Event>`

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="Venue_name",referencedColumnName = "name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="venue_location",referencedColumnName = "location")
})
```

Remove `@JoinColumns` and `@MapsId` from `Event` entity

Then you don't need to write

```
event.setVenue(venue);
```

Hope it helps.